# Error launching PowerShell - Cannot perform operation because object "runspace" has already been disposed

Tags: powershell, crash, runspace

When attempting to launch powershell, I get the following message:

> The shell cannot be started. A failure occurred during initialization:
>   Cannot perform operation because object "runspace" has already been disposed.
>   Object name: 'runspace'.

I can't seem to find any solutions via the google. Does anyone know if it's possible to uninstall/reinstall powershell from scratch?

Best,
Jon

Comment: AFAIK you can't fully uninstall from any OS except for XP but you could always try updating to the latest version and see if that changes anything.  beyond that were any changes made to the system recently?

Comment: Do you get the same error when you run `powershell.exe -NoExit -NoProfile` from a Command Prompt?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers this error occurs during PS initialize, so yes. However, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's not an absolute fix, but to anyone with the same problem: Restart your computer. I think I had some windows updates pending, as they deployed on reboot and then the problem went away.

Closing this question as this worked for me.